# Set widget container attributes dynamically

Tags: symfony

I'm busy with templating my forms inside Symfony 2.0.

It is possible to add attributes to a formfield like this:

```
$form->add('name', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'my_class')));
```

But how can I dynamically add attributes to the formfield widget? If i look to the form_div_layout.html.twig content, their is a

```
{{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}
```

which can load attributes, but I have no idea where I can add attributes to my FormBuilder in the Controller. Could anyone help me?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You should do that in twig layer:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {attr: {class: 'my_class'}}) }}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! But is it impossible to add this data in the Controller? What if the classname my_class is variable? If it's data from a database? It's strange that you can add field options, like attributes, in the controller itself. But you can't set any container options...

Comment: @ArneDeSmedt, `widget_container_attributes` use for `compound` field, and you can set `attr` like others, what's field type you want to set container attr? Alternative solution you may extend form theme (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)