# How can I set class for choices label element?

Tags: forms, symfony, styles

How can I add label class for choices elements? Is that even possible without doing it in the twig template ?

Rendered form choice element:

```
<div>
    <label class="required">Type</label>
    <div id="AddNewAdType_type">
        <input type="radio" id="AddNewAdType_type_0" name="AddNewAdType[type]" required="required" value="b">
        <label for="AddNewAdType_type_0" class="required">one</label> // add  css class here
        <input type="radio" id="AddNewAdType_type_1" name="AddNewAdType[type]" required="required" value="s">
        <label for="AddNewAdType_type_1" class="required">two</label> // add css class here
    </div>  
</div>
```

For example:

```
//...
    ->add("currency", "choice",[
            'choices'=>[
                '1' => 'one',
                '2' => 'two'
            ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_attr' =>[
            'class' => 'cssClassName' //won't work
            ]
    ])
//...
```

Comment: have you tried `label_attr`?

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583362/set-widget-container-attributes-dynamically

Answer (score -1):

```
 ->add("currency", "choice",[
            'choices'=>[
                '1' => 'one',
                '2' => 'two'
            ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'label_attr' =>[
            'class' => 'cssClassName' 
            ]
    ])
```

cheers!

Comment: You are adding labbel class to <label class="required">Type</label> to main choice label element. I would like to add class to choices label with in <div id="AddNewAdType_type"> .... </div>

Comment: it's the label class for the element and not for choice options!!